# weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException when export war file to Weblogic 12c R2

Tags: java, jax-rs, weblogic

I got a problem when my JAX-RS web-app export to Weblogic 12c R2. 
Is there have a problem with link libraries? or wrong setting?

Exception log stacktrace is blow.

```html
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
 at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:193)
 at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.startModule(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:1178)
 at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deployAutoGenerateEarApplication(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:843)
 at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1452)
 at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:944)
 at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:735)
 at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:584)
 at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
 at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3182)
 at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:355)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomWriters(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomWriters(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomReaders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomReaders(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomBuilders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomBuilders(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', [FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorize() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorize() at matching regular expression /authorize. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@714635c8', [FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorizeDecision() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorizeDecision() at matching regular expression /decision. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@2a133e40', [FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method POST and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorizeDecisionForm() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorizeDecisionForm(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap) at matching regular expression /decision. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@2a133e40']:org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException:Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomWriters(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomWriters(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomReaders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomReaders(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomBuilders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomBuilders(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', [FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorize() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorize() at matching regular expression /authorize. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@714635c8', [FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorizeDecision() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorizeDecision() at matching regular expression /decision. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@2a133e40', [FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method POST and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorizeDecisionForm() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorizeDecisionForm(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap) at matching regular expression /decision. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@2a133e40']
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:555)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:343)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:294)
 at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
 at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
 at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
 at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:87)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:673)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:612)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:2064)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:2041)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1930)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3101)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1843)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:884)
 at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
 at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
 at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
 at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
 at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
 at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
 at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
 at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
 at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
 at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
 at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
 at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
 at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
 at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
 at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
 at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
 at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
 at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
 at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
 at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
 at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
 at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
 at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
 at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
 at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
 at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
 at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
 at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
 at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
 at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
 at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
 at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
 at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
 at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
 at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
 at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
```

Also my weblogic.xml code is following this.

**updated** I add prefer-web-inf-classes element on my weblogic.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:context-root>myAppMain</wls:context-root>
    <wls:jsp-descriptor>
     <wls:encoding>UTF-8</wls:encoding>
    </wls:jsp-descriptor>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:charset-params>
     <wls:input-charset>
      <wls:resource-path>/*</wls:resource-path>
      <wls:java-charset-name>UTF-8</wls:java-charset-name>
     </wls:input-charset>
    </wls:charset-params>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

This is my libraries of the web-app.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM1GT.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kJi6.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUFbZ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMGTV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic comes with it's own JAX-RS Libraries, as well as many others API libraries that's the beauty and sometimes not so much about empresarial applications servers. So basically your Jersey Libraries are collapsing with the ones provided by the server, so you can do one of the two following alternatives.

1. Use the libraries already provided in the server. You can use JAX-RS libraries out of the box.
2. Go to WebLogic documentation in order to configure the server for not using its own libraries and take the Jersey one instead.

I would personally prefer the first alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm tried first method like blow at the weblogic.xml.
But it still same error. I'll update webloigic.xml in my question.